# S3 images downloading instead of displaying when uploading with Golang

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload an image to AWS S3.  The images are saving in the bucket but when I click on them (their URL) they download instead of displaying.  In the past this has been because the Content Type wasn't set to image/jpeg but I verified this time that it is.

Here's my code:

```
func UploadImageToS3(file os.File) error {

    fi, err := file.Stat() // get FileInfo
    if err != nil {
        return errors.New("Couldn't get FileInfo")
    }
    size := fi.Size()
    buffer := make([]byte, size)
    file.Read(buffer)
    tempFileName := "images/picturename.jpg" // key to save under

    putObject := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket:               aws.String("mybucket"),
        Key:                  aws.String(tempFileName),
        ACL:                  aws.String("public-read"), 
        Body:                 bytes.NewReader(buffer),
        ContentLength:        aws.Int64(int64(size)),

        // verified is properly getting image/jpeg
        ContentType:          aws.String(http.DetectContentType(buffer)),
    }

    _, err = AwsS3.PutObject(putObject)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err.Error())
        return err
    }
    return nil

}
```

I also tried making my `s3.PutObjectInput` as

```
putObject := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("mybucket"),
        Key:    aws.String(tempFileName),
        ACL:                  aws.String("public-read"), 
        Body: bytes.NewReader(buffer),
        ContentLength:        aws.Int64(int64(size)),
        ContentType: aws.String(http.DetectContentType(buffer)),
        ContentDisposition:   aws.String("attachment"),
        ServerSideEncryption: aws.String("AES256"),
        StorageClass:         aws.String("INTELLIGENT_TIERING"),
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Tried that but the same problem persists.  It downloads instead of displays.

Comment: @nightly Check `http.DetectContentType(buffer)` is `image/jpeg` or not ?
If http.DetectContentType can't detect then returned  ` `application/octet-stream` that may cause autodownload problem.

Comment: I figured it out.  See answer.  And yes, it was being set to image/jpeg.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.
Not totally sure why, but I needed to separate all the values.

```
var size int64 = fi.Size()
    buffer := make([]byte, size)
    file.Read(buffer)

    fileBytes := bytes.NewReader(buffer)
    fileType := http.DetectContentType(buffer)
    path := "images/test.jpeg"
    params := &s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket:        aws.String("mybucket"),
        Key:           aws.String(path),
        Body:          fileBytes,
        ContentLength: aws.Int64(size),
        ContentType:   aws.String(fileType),
    }
    _, err = AwsS3.PutObject(params)
```

If anyone knows why this works and the previous code doesn't, please share.

Comment: Body is set to fileBytes and ContnetType is set to fileType.  What are you talking about?

Comment: Well it worked when I used the 2nd way of doing things.